# Не изменяется изображение в header

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть сайт http://oaoenergomash.ru/.
Нужно поменять шапку.
Нахожу, где прописывается путь к шапке (файл `style.css`, 22-я строчка).
Изменяю файл на другой, сохраняю.
На сайте все без изменений, но в файле `style.css` прописана другая шапка.

Comment: почистить кеш необходимо

Comment: или замените на <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?v=1" type="text/css" />

Comment: Встречался с таким. 1) сначала удалял файл style.css 2) потом изменял его имя, к примеру, newStyle.css, загружал - и всё работало.